# How to print a new line character in LC-3?

Tags: assembly

Basically, I have input coming in which prints a result and loops back to the beginning, the problem is it keeps printing on the current line instead of printing the result on the new line... what could I do to fix this?

I think I've spent 2 hours trying to figure out how. Ive tried everything from .fill to .stringz and mindlessly using puts everywhere with random things in R0

Actual problem:
Im not sure if its a logical error in the code that also prints the previous thing that was printed... basically what happens is my output is :

```
Please enter digit: 1   <---- assume thats input
Please enter a digit: 0001 
Please enter a digit: Please enter a digit 4
Please enter a digit: 0100 
Please enter a digit: Please enter a digit: <wait for user input>
```

When it should be:

```
Please enter digit: 1   <---- assume thats input
0001
Please enter a digit 4
0100 
Please enter a digit <wait for user input>
```

Code:

```
.orig x3000

start    AND R0, R0, #0
     AND R1, R1, #0
     AND R2, R2, #0
     AND R3, R3, #0
     AND R4, R4, #0
     AND R5, R5, #0
     AND R6, R6, #0
     AND R7, R7, #0

lea r0, prompt
puts
lea r1, input

char    getc
putc
str r0, r1, #0
add r1, r1, #1
add r2, r0, #0

ld r3, check1       ;first check
add r2, r2, r3



add r4, r0, #0
add r5, r2, #0
and r2, r2, #0
getc
add r2, r0 #-10
brz cont


cont    and r0, r0, #0
and r2, r2, #0
add r0, r4, #0
add r2, r5, #0

brn incorrect

and r2, r2, #0
add r2, r0, #0
and r3, r3, #0

ld r3, check2       ;second check
add r2, r2, r3
brzp incorrect

add r4, r0, #0
and r0, r0, #0
and r2, r0, #0
add r2, r2, #10

body    and r0, r0 #0
add r0, r4, #0
and r2, r2, #0      ;numbers 0-9 that make it pass checks
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test0
add r2, r0, r3
brz case0

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test1
add r2, r0, r3
brz case1

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test2
add r2, r0, r3
brz case2

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test3
add r2, r0, r3
brz case3

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test4
add r2, r0, r3
brz case4

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test5
add r2, r0, r3
brz case5

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test6
add r2, r0, r3
brz case6

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test7
add r2, r0, r3
brz case7

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test8
add r2, r0, r3
brz case8

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test9
add r2, r0, r3
brz case9

test0       .fill -48
case0       lea r0, empty
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string0
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test1       .fill -49
case1       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string1
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test2       .fill -50
case2       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string2
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test3       .fill -51
case3       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string3
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test4       .fill -52
case4       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string4
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test5       .fill -53
case5       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string5
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test6       .fill -54
case6       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string6
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test7       .fill -55
case7       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string7
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test8       .fill -56
case8       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string8
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

test9       .fill -57
case9       lea r0, eol
    puts
    lea r0, string9
    puts
    lea r0, eol
    puts
    brnzp start

string0     .stringz "0000"
string1     .stringz "0001"
string2     .stringz "0010"
string3     .stringz "0101"
string4     .stringz "0100"
string5     .stringz "0101"
string6     .stringz "0110"
string7     .stringz "0111"
string8     .stringz "1000"
string9     .stringz "1001"


empty       .fill 0
eol     .fill 10
prompt      .stringz "Enter a digit: "
check1      .fill -48
check2      .fill -58
incorrect   halt
input       .blkw 10

.end
```

Comment: Find the OS' newline hex code and print that?

Comment: By removing the code you invalidate the answer. That is frowned upon. Please don't do that.

Comment: Rene, I have removed my code on purpose, would it be possible if you could kindly take it down as well as Chris's answer which contains my code? or at least fragments of it, I could get into serious trouble with the University, I only wanted tiny help with a printing error, but posting my code can be a serious offence.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that would be the case but by posting you agreed to the terms of this site and that simply means you no longer own the content. See this meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268036/why-cant-i-delete-my-posts/268037#268037. Stack Overflow is not only here to help you but also wants to be useful for future visitors. For that they needs your original code.

Comment: Im really sorry I didnt know.... I could get into serious trouble with the department by posting my code in case other students may copy my code.. I beg you to take this down

Comment: Here is another post from a moderator on the same topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316118/578411, one option you might consider is to flag your question and ask it to be disassociated from your account. In that case the post stays up but is no longer linked to you.

Comment: I will do that, but I would really like it if my source code was removed or the question was removed altogether, even if it was not linked to my account the source code would still be out there and so I would be disrespecting the universities guidelines which could have me in serious legal issues. This was an honest mistake, I thought that I was able to remove the question and award Chris the points after it had been made. My honest apologies, is there any chance this can be removed?

Comment: You can try to flag your question for moderator attention and explain why it needs to be deleted/edited/redacted but if it is just to cover up your mistake I don't have high hopes. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I better understand what you're trying to do.

All you need to do is make sure `R0` contains the value '10' ( or 'A' if you're working with hex) and then print it out with `putc`

```
.ORIG x3000

    LD R0, ENDLINE      ; R0 = the value of ENDLINE
    PUTc                ; Prints the char in R0
    TRAP x25            ; halt

; data segment
ENDLINE .FILL x0A       ; A decimal 10, or a hex 'A'
.END
```

---

Other than that I would need to see the code to help debug it. From what I can tell you have R0 pointing to your 'Please enter a digit:' string, printing that, and then printing the '0001'. It's possible your null char at the end of your string was replaced by the start of '0001' and so it's a run-on. But that's all speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, it looks like when you're trying to print a new line char you're loading the pointer value of `eol` into `R0` when you need to ascii value of 10 stored in `R0`. After that you need to use the `PUTc` command to print a single char. I've made those small changes below and now it works as expected.

.

```
.orig x3000

start    AND R0, R0, #0
AND R1, R1, #0
AND R2, R2, #0
AND R3, R3, #0
AND R4, R4, #0
AND R5, R5, #0
AND R6, R6, #0
AND R7, R7, #0

lea r0, prompt
puts
lea r1, input

char    getc
putc
str r0, r1, #0
add r1, r1, #1
add r2, r0, #0

ld r3, check1; first check
add r2, r2, r3



add r4, r0, #0
add r5, r2, #0
and r2, r2, #0
getc
add r2, r0 # - 10
brz cont


cont    and r0, r0, #0
and r2, r2, #0
add r0, r4, #0
add r2, r5, #0

brn incorrect

and r2, r2, #0
add r2, r0, #0
and r3, r3, #0

ld r3, check2; second check
add r2, r2, r3
brzp incorrect

add r4, r0, #0
and r0, r0, #0
and r2, r0, #0
add r2, r2, #10

body    and r0, r0 #0
add r0, r4, #0
and r2, r2, #0; numbers 0 - 9 that make it pass checks
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test0
add r2, r0, r3
brz case0

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test1
add r2, r0, r3
brz case1

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test2
add r2, r0, r3
brz case2

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test3
add r2, r0, r3
brz case3

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test4
add r2, r0, r3
brz case4

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test5
add r2, r0, r3
brz case5

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test6
add r2, r0, r3
brz case6

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test7
add r2, r0, r3
brz case7

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test8
add r2, r0, r3
brz case8

and r2, r2, #0
and r3, r3, #0
ld r3, test9
add r2, r0, r3
brz case9

test0.fill - 48
case0
ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string0
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test1.fill - 49
case1       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string1
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test2.fill - 50
case2       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string2
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test3.fill - 51
case3       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string3
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test4.fill - 52
case4       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string4
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test5.fill - 53
case5       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string5
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test6.fill - 54
case6       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string6
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test7.fill - 55
case7       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string7
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test8.fill - 56
case8       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string8
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

test9.fill - 57
case9       ld r0, eol
putc
lea r0, string9
puts
ld r0, eol
putc
brnzp start

string0.stringz "0000"
string1.stringz "0001"
string2.stringz "0010"
string3.stringz "0101"
string4.stringz "0100"
string5.stringz "0101"
string6.stringz "0110"
string7.stringz "0111"
string8.stringz "1000"
string9.stringz "1001"


empty.fill 0
eol.fill x0A
prompt.stringz "Enter a digit: "
check1.fill - 48
check2.fill - 58
incorrect   halt
input.blkw 10

.end
```